# download file from IP camera with URL http://admin:password@cameraIP/images/snapshot.jpg in python3 script

Tags: url, download, credentials

I'm trying to dowload camera still image using URL

http://admin:password@cameraIP/images/snapshot.jpg

I have tried with urlib:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

username = 'admin'
password = 'password'

url = 'http://192.168.212.214/images/snapshot.jpg'
filename = 'test_image.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username,password))

print(r.status_code)
```

I'm getting 401 status

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://admin:password@192.168.212.214/images/snapshot.jpg'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

it complains for invalid literal (it is trying to parse everything after colon as TCP port)

Does someone have any suggestions?